# How to change the percentage text color in MPAndroidChart PieChart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have a PieChart in my App using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library but by default the chart slice percentage text is all white. Managed to change the percentage color but couldn't do the same for it's description text. See the image below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for `PieChart#setEntryLabelColor(int)`

Comment: Yup you nailed it. I was searching this under DataSet as I thought that might have it. Anyways thanks for the help.

pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.BLACK);